# Can a user purchase a consumable and a non-consumable together?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm starting to see developers on IOS implement "if you buy a coin pack you'll also get all ads removed". From my understand of IOS in-app purchase I assume the coin pack as consumables, which would be $0.99, and ads removal as non-consumable, which I assume would be free, but how will I make the transaction? Will I make a payment request for the consumables and non-consumable together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is NO. While it might be possible to add two payments to payment queue in a row, it is important for user to understand that he is buying two products together. If you do addPayment twice, the entire flow will run twice, with alerts nagging the buyer - something that you don't want.

In such a case, you better make it so that consumable purchase unlocks the app so that ads do not appear. Single product - with description stating they got ad-removal as permanent bonus.

The ultimate difference between consumable and non-consumable is simply the fact that you can't restore consumables, so you must find a way to store that consumable somewhere, so your app knows to remove ads in case of device change / app deletion.

When you hear other devs offering similar, they are actually selling just one product at a time.

It is possible to sell >1 quantity of an IAP item, though.

Comment: Ok, that's understandable. The only reason I was thinking of making ad removal non-consumable was for the restore transaction data. So would you recommend I store that data in something like ICloud for cross device retrieval?

Comment: Yes icloud keychain would be the first preference. You would anyway need something to store your consumables for catastrophic consequences (deletion etc).